# Plotting heatmap with Gnuplot in C++

Tags: c++, gnuplot, heatmap

```
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include "gnuplot-iostream.h"

int main()
{
    float frame[4][4];
    for (int n=0; n<4; n++)
    {
        for (int m=0; m<4; m++)
        {
        frame[n][m]=n+m;
        }
    }
    Gnuplot gp;
    gp << "unset key\n";
    gp << "set pm3d\n";
    gp << "set hidden3d\n";
    gp << "set view map\n";
    gp << "set xrange [ -0.500000 : 3.50000 ] \n";
    gp << "set yrange [ -0.500000 : 3.50000 ] \n";
    gp << "splot '-'\n";
    gp.send2d(frame);
    gp.flush();
}
```

This generates me an image:

[image]

The problem is, that element "frame[0][0]" should be black in this color palette. And I suppose it is black, but the area between four points is colored in blue (color for average value of these four points).
What I want, that I could generate an image like this:
[link to gnuplot heatmap example](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/heatmaps.html).
It actually colors a matrix element, not the area between four elements.
So how do I do that using C++ and an iostream pipe?
I can print data to a file and then plot from that file, but this can be slow...
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You must use the `image` plotting style, just like done in the demo page you linked:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include "gnuplot-iostream.h"

int main()
{
    float frame[4][4];
    for (int n=0; n<4; n++)
    {
        for (int m=0; m<4; m++)
        {
        frame[n][m]=n+m;
        }
    }
    Gnuplot gp;
    gp << "unset key\n";
    gp << "set autoscale fix\n";
    gp << "plot '-' with image\n";
    gp.send2d(frame);
    gp.flush();
}
```

I cannot test it right now, but that should do the trick. Maybe you need to change the `set autoscale` part to fit your needs. Using `set autoscale fix` uses tight ranges for all axes (x, y, and color).

Comment: Hi! There's one problem. The send2d() sends a singe column to gnuplot. The `image` does not like it and requires three columns. Anyhow, the user usually wants to pass x, y, color coordinates, too. I'm also not sure how send2d() knows the size of the float array. Also the website states that one should avoid simple arrays and prefer `std::vector` or similar.
See https://gitorious.org/gnuplot-iostream/pages/Datatypes

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Christoph! I tried using "send1d()" and somehow it worked! But now it shows graph only after closing iostream pipe. And if I want to replot, I have to close "Gnuplot" object and create new one and this creates a new plot window. It seems like I need some termination or smth...

Comment: @sweber You are right. I hadn't checked the format written by `send2d()`. I thought if it fits splot it should fit also with image :)