# How does gnuplot C++ api know where a pointer ends?

Tags: c++, gnuplot

I want to draw a heatmap in C++ and I came across this code : [Plotting heatmap with Gnuplot in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777605/plotting-heatmap-with-gnuplot-in-c)

In `gp.send2d(frame);` all what the function send2d is seeing is a float*, so how does it know the dimensions (4x4) ? Or even that it can access safely 16 elements ?

Comment: Most likely it takes the object by reference and array sizes are part of the object.

Comment: FWIW, you could look at the [source](https://github.com/dstahlke/gnuplot-iostream/blob/master/gnuplot-iostream.h#L1769).

Comment: My C++ skills are rusty but I'm pretty sure an array decays to a pointer to its first element when passed to a function, so no possibility to pass an array by reference...

Comment: It is possible to pass an array by reference in C++, but it is unlikely gnuplot is doing that.

Comment: I take it back about it being unlikely that gnuplot does that ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The size of the array is part of its type.  In the example you link to `frame` is a `float[4][4]`.  Since [`send2d()`](https://github.com/dstahlke/gnuplot-iostream/blob/master/gnuplot-iostream.h#L1769) is declared as

```
template <typename T> Gnuplot &send2d(const T &arg)
```

It will deduce the type of `T` to be `float[4][4]` and make `arg` a reference to that.  Expanded out that would look like

```
Gnuplot &send2d(const float (&arg)[4][4])
```

Which shows that `arg` is a reference 2d array.  There is no decay to a pointer here since we have a reference.

Here is an example that shows that using references maintains the array trype instead of decaying to a pointer

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T & arr_2d)
{
    for (auto& row : arr_2d)
    {
        for (auto& col : row)
            std::cout << col << " ";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}


int main() 
{
    int bar[2][2] = {1,2,3,4};
    foo(bar);
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 
3 4
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/441dcecdc87517d2)</kbd>